# postgresql: how can i create a new server in postgres addational to another server?

Tags: postgresql

I have a server in my postgres and I want to develop a new project, for that project I want to create a new server, and I didn't seccess, How can I do that?

Comment: Just create another database. But this is not related to programming so I advice you to ask at https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: Do you actually want a new Postgres server or a new Postgres database in the existing Postgres cluster? Also more information needed 1) OS and version? 2) How did you install the existing Postgres server?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I seccessded to create a new database, But it's 2 defferent projects, and I don't want mix between them, How can I do that? and what the different between server and database?

Comment: A server is an instance of a Postgres install and starts out with three databases; template0, template1 and postgres.  You can then add your own databases to this instance. In order to get  a new server you need to create a new Postgres instance. That can be done manually or depending on where you installed from it can be done through the installation procedure. That is why it is important to know your OS and how you installed Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous but hopefully this will help. You either want one of two things, a new database on the same instance/server or a new instance/server entirely. I"m assuming they are running on the same box.

1. You can issue a `create database` command on a running database and you will have a separate one. This share the same instance as any existing databases you have running. You would connect with `psql -d [databasename] -h host -p port`

[create database docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

or

2. You create a new instance with the initdb command, change the config to use a different port. This way you can have more than one instance running on the same box. You would connect as above just changing the port number.

[initdb from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)

[postgresql.conf examplefile](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample)

Comment: Depending on how Postgres was installed 2) can be done by the install procedure in a manner that makes it easier to manage then the manual method you show. You should update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: OP doesn't mention an install method so I went for the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Which means you have an incomplete answer.